# Conversion of milliseconds to seconds is not working in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show the time taken by a process in label.
So I implemented `watch`.

Now let say process took 7 miliseconds and I want to show it in seconds so I wrote `7/1000` which should be `0.007` but its showing `0`.

I am showing it into label, so if any conversions of string can show this format please suggest me.

Comment: `7.0/1000`, `(double)7/1000`, `7/1000.0`, `7/(double)1000`

Comment: Show the code of watch. Also what type are you using to store the amount of the seconds?

Comment: You are using int devision use float devision like this 1f/1000f

Comment: Emad your solution worked :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You're not posting any code, but I suppose that you divide two integer values. Integer division always results in an integer as well.

If you divide `7/1000.0` instead (and/or cast at least one operand to a floating-point number, e.g. `double`) the division will give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an `int` which will not have decimal points. try and change it to a `double`.

The simplest fix here would be to change your calculation to

```
seconds/1000.0
```